# @Nullable @Named in GAE / Android Sample

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to work on the sample GAE / Android app. There is Place Entity.

In generated PlaceEndpoint class there is a method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listGame")
    public CollectionResponse<Place> listPlace(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        EntityManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Game> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Place as Place");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Game>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Game obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<Game> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }
```

As I understand `cursor` and `limit` all optional params.

However I can't figure out how to pass them using `Placeednpoint` class on the client side:

```
Placeendpoint.Builder builder = new Placeendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), null);
builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
Placeendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

try {
    CollectionResponsePlace placesResponse = endpoint.listPlace().execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Normally, when params are not nullable I would pass them in endpoint.listPlace() method. But when params are nullable, client side app doesn't see alternative constructor, that would accept params.

How am I supposed to pass them then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For passing parameters from client side while sending a query request through cloud endpoints, you need to add provision for setting parameters. To send the required parameter from android , the class where you would define the REST Path and method type, should include an option to the set cursor and limit. For example for the String **cursorstring** :

```
@com.google.api.client.util.Key
      private String cursorstring;

      public String getCursorstring() {
        return cursorstring;
      }

      public ListPlace setCursorstring(String cursorstring) {
        this.cursorstring = cursorstring;
        return this;
      }
```

Finally while calling the endpoint method from your android code, you should pass a value using the setCursorstring, which will be something like:

```
CollectionResponsePlace placesResponse = endpoint.listPlace().setCursorstring("yourcursorstring").execute();
```

Comment: then what the @Nullable param is for? I can aswell remove it right?

Comment: I am not sure about java based backend, since I use python. please confirm with sample code for google cloud endpoints using java. for whatever parameter you need to send from android through cloud endpoints, have the setter methods as mentioned above for each parameter and process them in your app engine backend. if you are not using any variable in your backend code, you can try removing

Comment: How would you do this with the iOS client library? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional way. You can simply set your nullable value 'cursor' it like this:

```
CollectionResponsePlace placesResponse = 
     endpoint.listPlace().set("cursor", "Your Cursorstring").execute();
```

Where you can

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue but backend developed using Java.
The solution provided by Tony m worked like a charm.
Simply had to adapt how the method is called on Android and it worked.