# Pass List<Strings> argument to endpoint

Tags: android, facebook, google-app-engine, endpoints

I am writing an android game using Google endpoints.

We want to check who of facebook user friends uses also our app (each user gets his own id in the game and his facebook id is the String field of entity User).

So I get the list of friends facebook ids into List and want to pass it to server using endpoints and make some queries of type: `select n from User n where n.facebookId IN ("+listOfFriends+")`
The problem is the I can't pass the List to endpoints.

I made container class:

```
@Entity
public class StringsListContainer {
    private List<String> listString;

    public List<String> getStringsList() {
        return listString;
    }
    public void setStringsList(List<String> objectsList) {
        this.listString = objectsList;
    }
    public StringsListContainer(List<String> listString) {
        this.listString = listString;
    }
}
```

And in UserEndpoints my Api is:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "getTopFriendsForUser")
public CollectionResponse<User> getTopFriendsForUser(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit,
        StringsListContainer friendsLine) {
    System.out.println( "In getTopFriendsForUser endpoint" );
    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<User> execute= new ArrayList<User>();

        //next will go in chunks depending on size of StringsList
    for(String s : friendsLine.getStringsList())
    {
        if(listOfFriends.isEmpty()) {
            listOfFriends = "'" + s + "'";
        } else {
            listOfFriends = listOfFriends + ",'" + s + "'";
        }
    }

    System.out.println( listOfFriends.toString());

        try {
            mgr = getEntityManager();
            Query query = mgr.createQuery("select n from User n where n.facebookId IN ("+listOfFriends+")");
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(0);
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
            }
            execute = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
            cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            for (User obj : execute)
                ;
            System.out.println("Ending");
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }


    return CollectionResponse.<User> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}
```

I generating client libraries and calling it from client like this:

```
CollectionResponseUser response = endpoint.getTopFriendsForUser(friendsList).execute();
```

Still I get `The method getTopFriendsForUser() in the type Userendpoint is not applicable for the arguments (StringsListContainer)` error

Can anyone advice how to solve this? 
Or maybe there is a better way to check it?

Comment: Same Question I have.
An answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147670/nullable-named-in-gae-android-sample
But I can't find anything to back it up and It doesn't seem like the best way to do things. I'm hoping for a better idea. 

It's been a while since you asked the question, did you figure out a way?