# Annotating optional param with @Nullable in google app engine Endpoints drops the parameter

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

```
@ApiMethod(name = "foo")
public void foo(@Nullable @Named("bar") String bar, User auth) throws OAuthRequestException
```

ends up generating an API where the `foo` method takes NO bar parameter. If I do not annotate with @Nullable, and just pass null from the client, I get an exception at runtime.

I'm sure this must be supported and I'm just doing something stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of googling, found the answer here
[@Nullable @Named in GAE / Android Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147670/nullable-named-in-gae-android-sample)

Basically, endpoints will generate a setXXX method which will accept your optional parameter. You ARE allowed to pass null to it so no need for if/else check where you only invoke the set API if your param is not null. Nifty.

Comment: I think this behaviour changed from the version 2.0.3 to 2.2.1 at least. Now I need to put `@com.google.api.server.spi.config.Nullable` or `@javax.annotation.Nullable`. If I want a null parameter to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

was delayed understood without an example, here I write to compliment response of @Creos

```
collectionResponse = myApiService.activityByDay(idWebSafeFamily, token.getToken(), token.getTokenIdWebSafe(), nextPageToken).setIdUser(idUser).execute();
```